# Mysql use IN with subquery

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to execute the following query, but mySQL is not supporting it.

```
UPDATE `TABLE 1` SET `batchid`=1 WHERE `id` 
IN (SELECT `id` FROM `TABLE 1` 
    WHERE `postcode` BETWEEN "3699*" 
     AND "3900*" AND `telstriplengte`='10' LIMIT 1);
```

I've been fiddling around with JOINS but can't seem to get it right. My question is if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this `*` wildcard in `BETWEEN "3699*" AND "3900*"`? Because `BETWEEN` does not support such.

Comment: ...And why you use IN with subquery for the same table? You can simply make `UPDATE table_1 SET ... WHERE postcode BETWEEN "3699*" AND "3900*" AND telstriplengte='10'`.

Comment: Are the `postcode`s and the `telstriplengte`s really strings? At least the latter seems unlikely to me, so better do `telstriplengte=10`.

Comment: My answer is : Yes someone could point you in right direction :P

Answer (score 3):

Can't you pass directly all in one query like that?

```
UPDATE `TABLE 1` SET `batchid`=1
WHERE `postcode` BETWEEN "36990" AND "39009" AND `telstriplengte`='10' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE `TABLE 1`
    SET `batchid`=1
    WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id`
                   FROM `TABLE 1`
                   WHERE `postcode` BETWEEN "3699*" AND "3900*" AND
                         `telstriplengte`='10'
                   LIMIT 1);
```

The specific problem with this query is that you are referring to the table being updated in the subquery.  In this case -- assuming that `id` i unique, you don't need the subquery at all:

```
UPDATE `TABLE 1`
    SET `batchid`=1
    WHERE `postcode` BETWEEN "3699*" AND "3900*" 
    AND `telstriplengte` = '10'
    LIMIT 1;
```

Normally when using `LIMIT` you also have an `ORDER BY`.  Not required, but any row could be updated that matches the conditions, and I'm guessing you want the one with the smallest id.